# Java - MySQL - NullPointerException in catch

Tags: java, mysql, bukkit

I am making a bukkit plugin which uses MySQL, but I keep getting a null pointer exception on this code and I can't find anyone with the same error. How can I get rid of this error?

Just for information, this is the connect method in the same class:

```
public void connect() {
    try 
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        stat = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database + "?user=" + user + "&password=" + password).createStatement();

        stat.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tokens` (`Name` varchar(32),`amount` int)");
    } 

    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
    catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Method that gives the error:

```
public void createAccount(String player) throws SQLException {
    try 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(player);

        String name = sc.next();

        String SQLText = "SELECT * FROM `tokens` WHERE name='" + name + "'";

        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(SQLText);

        if (!rs.next())
        {

            // This code is not here yet
        }

        sc.close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex) 
    {  
    plugin.log.info("There is something wrong in the MySQLHandler: " + ex.toString()); // This gives me the nullpointerexception
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably good to provide stack.. though, I'd think just checking if `plugin == null`, might set you on the right track.

Comment: add your stacktrace in question

Comment: Hard to say without Stack Trace, but chances are that `plugin` is `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot work this way, with a global Statement field `stat`.

Connections, statements and result sets should be closed.

Look at examples, preferably with PreparedStatement, and try-with-resources.

Also user and password may be given as separate paramters.

```
try (PreparedStatemen stat = connection.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT 1 FROM tokens WHERE name=? LIMIT 1")) {
    stat.setString(1, name);
    try (ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery()) {
        if (!rs.next()) {
            return "Not found";
        }
    }
}
```

Above `stat` and `rs` are closed, even despite the return.

Prepared statements do not need the single quote put in the SQL string, and escape single quote, backslash etc. Also SQL injection, malicious input is prevented.

Comment: Thanks! this will certainly help

Answer (score 1):

When you have the line that throws an NPE

```
  plugin.log.info("There is something wrong in the MySQLHandler: " + ex.toString()); // This gives me the nullpointerexception
```

the following variables could be null:

- plugin
- plugin.log
- ex (this should not happen as an caucht exception is not null!)

You could try the following to check what is null (just for debuggin purpose, not in your productive code):

```
} catch (...)
    if (plugin == null) System.out.println("plugin is null");
    if (plugin.log == null) System.out.println("plugin.log is null");
    //...
}
```